# Add fade in/out effect to logos in header when they switch from one to the other on scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, css, fadein, fadeout

I have logo1 in the header changing to logo2 when user scrolls down. However, I don't want the logos to instantly switch but rather the first logo gradually fade out as the second logo fades in.   I have added .fadeIn(slow) and .fadeOut(slow) in various places in my js but it's had no effect.  Hoping I can get some help with this.

I've updated my question with more code. I've had 2 answers but can't get either to work for me and no more responses. Hoping an edited question with more detail will get a bit more attention.

```
<header>
        <div id="nav" class="navbar">
            <div id="nav_left">
                <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
                <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
            </div>
            <a href="index.html" id="logo" class="Claire_logo">
                <img src="images/logo_6_small.png" alt="logo2" id="logo_Claire" class="logo_main"
                    style="display:none" />
                <img src="images/logo_bluebird_90_cc.png" alt="logo1" id="logo_Claire_blue" class="logo" />
            </a>
            <div id="nav_right">
                <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
                <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
                <a href="contact.html">GET IN TOUCH</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll > 0) {
        $(".navbar").addClass("navbar-scroll");
        $(".logo").show();
      } else {
        $(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-scroll");
        $(".logo").hide();
      }
      if (scroll > 120) {
        // $(".navbar").addClass("nav-color");
        $(".logo_main").show();
        $(".logo").hide();
      } else {
        // $(".navbar").removeClass("nav-color");
        $(".logo_main").hide();
        $(".logo").show();
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: You can do that using `replaceWith` method in jQuery. I have posted a demo of working snippet for the same

Answer (score 0):

I edited my answer. I missed the error in your code. I commented below in codes. You can use both fadeIn & fadeOut or show & hide methods as well. But for fadeing effect using fadeIn & fadeOut maybe looks better than show & hide

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
          var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
          if (scroll >= 0 && scroll <= 120) { // I missed this logic mistake for the first time. 
            $(".navbar").addClass("navbar-scroll");
            $(".logo").fadeIn(300); // or show(300)
          } else {
            $(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-scroll");
            $(".logo").fadeOut(0); // or hide()
          }
          if (scroll > 120) {
            // $(".navbar").addClass("nav-color");
            $(".logo_main").fadeIn(300);
            $(".logo").fadeOut(0);
          } else {
            // $(".navbar").removeClass("nav-color");
            $(".logo_main").fadeOut(0);
            $(".logo").fadeIn(300);
          }
        });
      });
```

Comment: Definitely can't get this to give met the fade in/out effect I'm going for. Could you show this being used in the code I shared in my original post?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `jQuery` `replaceWith`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 0) {
      $('#oldlogo').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('#oldlogo').replaceWith('<div id="newlogo"><img src="newlogo" alt="newlogo"/></div>').fadeIn(500);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh
}

header {
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}

#nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div id="nav" class="navbar">
    <div id="oldlogo"> <img src="oldlogooldlogo" alt="oldlogo" /></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I can't get this to work for me. I'm going to edit with my new code. Hopefully you can point out what I've done wrong.   Thank you for the help

Comment: I got this to work but there is no smooth transition from first logo to second. The first logo fades out nicely and then the second one sort of pops up rather than slowly fading in at the same time.